# Separate expressjs applications

Tags: node.js, express

I googled a lot about how to have separate expressjs routes, but none of them helped me.
I have following structure.

```
+-- account
|   +-- views
|   |   +-- signin.jade
|   +-- route.js
|   app.js
|   route.js
```

I need to implement user account related stuff in a different express app which I called it `account`.
Here is what I have in my `account/route.js`:

```
var express   = require('express'),
    router    = express.Router();

var signIn = function(req, res) {
   res.render('signin', {title: 'Sign In'});
}
var signOut = function(req, res) {
   // sign out process
}

router.get('/signin', signIn);
router.get('/signout', signOut);

module.exports = router;
```

And this is my `route.js`:

```
var express   = require('express'),
    router    = express.Router();

var index = function(req, res, next) {
    // home page
}

router.get('/', index);

module.exports = router;
```

And finally my `app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
...
// other stuff
...
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use('/', require('./route'));
app.use('/account', require('./account/route'));
```

Now when I run my application and navigate to `account/signin` I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "signin" in views directory "/home/sina/dev/test/views"
```

I am using ExpressJS 4.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Your templates are located in `account/views`, but you're telling Express to look for them in `views`. Try this:</s>

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'account', 'views'));
```

If you want to support more than one app, there are two solutions that I can think of.

First is to change your directory structure so all the views are located in the same parent directory:

```
+-- views
|   +----- account
|   |      +------- signin.jade
|   +----- anotherapp
|   |      +------- anotherfile.jade
|  ...
+-- account
|   +------ route.js
|  ...
|
```

Another option is to create sub apps, instead of plain routers. For example, your `account/route.js` would look like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

var signIn = function(req, res) {
   res.render('signin', {title: 'Sign In'});
}
var signOut = function(req, res) {
   // sign out process
}

app.get('/signin', signIn);
app.get('/signout', signOut);

module.exports = app;
```

This sets the view path to be specific to the app (however, I haven't tested this extensively).

Comment: I have another `route` file as I mentioned.  'app.use('/', require('./route'));'
If I add `account` to `views` directory I will get `Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/home/sina/dev/text/account/views"`. I need to have both `account` route and my ordinary routes work properly.

Comment: does `res.render('account/signin'); res.render('anotherapp/anotherfile')` work?

Comment: @sadrzadehsina yeah I figured. I edited my answer to provide two solutions.

Comment: @Plato I don't see how that could work, given that Express is told to only look in `./views` (and not `./account/views` or `./anotherapp/views`)

Comment: @robertklep with your new solution should I still have `app.use('/account', require('./account/route'));` in my main `app.js` file. Because I get the following error: `Router.use() requires middleware function but got a string`

Comment: @sadrzadehsina err sorry, my bad, typo in the code. Fixed.

Comment: @robertklep It works now :) would you please tell me do I have two different expressjs applications now? Are they listening on the same port?!

Comment: @sadrzadehsina with Express you can nest apps, so one app can use another app. They are still part of the same overall "root app" (so to speak), so you still just need one port to access both (and you can probably share resources between them, too, like sessions etc).